# from attribute in json on python

Tags: python, json

I called an url that returns me a json object with an attribute called `from`. So when i want to get this in python i try:

```
object.from.username

$ python sample_app.py
  File "sample_app.py", line 63
    print comment.from.username
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from` is a python keyword and should not be used as an attribute.

Lucky for you, when using the `json` library that comes with python, JSON objects become dictionaries instead:

```
object['from']['username']
```

For situations where you actually do have a object with a python keyword used as an attribute, you'd have to resort to using the `getattr()` function instead:

```
frm = getattr(object, 'from')
```

Comment: I don't know that I'd say it *can't* be used as an attribute -- It just can't be accessed using the `.` operator and therefore *shouldn't* be used as an attribute ;-) -- You can do whatever you want with `getattr` and `setattr` ... but that's a very minor nitpick

Comment: @mgilson: There, expanded; I was planning to add that anyway, but I am multitasking again..